# Number input halves in size when using min and max

Tags: html

When making an input, like so:

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="100"><br>
<input type="number" min="0" max="99"><br>
<input type="number" min="1" max="100"><br>
<input type="number" min="1" max="99"><br>
```

It shortens the width of the input field, specifically when max is at 100. Since i've never seen this, i can only guess it does this thinking i will use percentages or currency, which i actually do, but i do not want this. Is there another way to prevent this from happening besides using different values or changing the size of the input yourself?

Comment: apply `width` of the input box .The will prevent the box size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of how *some** browsers render those inputs. So the answer is **No**. If you want to have certain width, take a look at the other answers.

* Different browsers render elements differently:

[image]

And this is the result of your snippet in Mozilla Firefox:

[image]

Comment: Alright, then custom width it is. I thought it would've been nice to have a command for this that i didn't know of like readonly and required, but CSS it is. Thank you. :)

Comment: You can set width using the `width` attribute. It is a valid attribute of every input. But since you said *"prevent this from happening by changing the size of the input yourself"*, I thought that this was not an option for you.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. What i meant is to simply find out if this could be done without using the obvious alternatives. I used CSS now though, so it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

The input field width adapts to the width of the highest value: 100. 99 has one less character, so the input field is shorter. I don't think you can prevent that difference without CSS if your max values have a different character length.

Now, CSS should be a piece of cake....

```html
<style>.medium-input {width:100px;}</style>
<input type="number" min="0" max="100"  class="medium-input"><br>
<input type="number" min="0" max="99"  class="medium-input"><br>
<input type="number" min="1" max="100"  class="medium-input"><br>
<input type="number" min="1" max="99"  class="medium-input"><br>
```

I'm adding the same class to all of the inputs, so that you can also define some other lengths if you like.
You could also do it with `input[type=number]` as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

you can add css to control the width of inputs.
this will do the job :

```
input[type=number]{
 width: 150px;
}
```